# Maximum heap space constraints in java

Tags: java, jvm

I have a program that needs a lot of memory and want to set the maximum heap space at 6024MB.
Java gives me the error:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx6024m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: As Thomas Lötzer pointed out, the problem could be that you're trying to do this in a 32 bit environment. If that's not the case, please tell us a bit about your JVM and OS environment!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I seem to be working in a 32 bit enviroment :(

Comment: ok. how much of RAM does the box have (and that you can use) and are there any other boxes whose RAM you can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are big differences between how many heap one can allocate between the different Java VMs. E.g. Sun's VM needs to allocate the memory as a single block from the OS. This limitation does not exist for Oracle's [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/index.html) VM. It is also OS dependent -- e.g. I was able to allocate more heap with Sun's VM using Linux than was possible with Windows XP. Also note that I read somewhere that the problem goes away for 64bit OSes...

Edit:

[Here's a blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/why_can_t_i_allocate) about Sun's JVM and Java heap space issues on 32bit Windows OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a 64 bit VM? If so, you should be able to use the switch as you did.